# In "Para ti y otros niños como tú", both "ti" and "tú" translate as "you" in English or "toi" in French. How to understand which one to use and when?

Tags: traducción, gramática, pronombres

Hello dear spanish friends.
In the sentence :

> Para **ti** y otros niños como **tú**

Both of them are personnal pronouns, but **ti** is "oblique personnal pronoun" and **tú** is a "nominative personal pronoun".

It's very confusing since in French, we would say "Pour **toi** et d'autres enfants comme **toi**"

In English, we would say "for **you** and other kids like **you**"

So, can somebody explain why and when should we use "ti" or "tú", there must be a coherent grammatical rule behind this.

Best Regards, Marcello

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"para" is a preposition, and we always use object (not subject) pronouns after prepositions:

- mí
- ti

"como" is a conjunction, not a preposition, and as a result a subject pronoun will be required:

- yo
- tú

However, in the third person "él, "ella" and "usted" (formal second person treatment taking 3rd person singular verb), object pronoun "sí" will be reflexive and the mentioned pronouns will work after a preposition:

- Para **él/ella/usted** y otras personas como **él/ella/usted**.

In the plural, we use the same pronouns, "nosotros/vosotros/ustedes/ellos" in both cases.

Comment: Cheers for the great answer. Is 'object pronouns' the same with "pronombres de preposición' ?